# Pass Credentials to access Network Drive using Groovy

Tags: groovy, groovy-console

I have a requirement of automating the file copy from one shared drive location to another shared drive. I have instructed to use Groovy for the same.

I'm completely new to Groovy. I managed to copy the file using targetlocation << sourcelocation.text. But it requires a username and password to access the shared drive. I'm not sure how to do that.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What kind of shared drive?

Answer (score 1):

If it is a Windows or Samba share, you could use jcifs to connect:

```
import jcifs.smb.SmbFile
import jcifs.smb.NtlmPasswordAuthentication
import jcifs.context.BaseContext
import jcifs.CIFSContext
import jcifs.config.PropertyConfiguration
import jcifs.Configuration

Configuration config = new PropertyConfiguration(new Properties())
CIFSContext context = new BaseContext(config)
context = context.withCredentials(new NtlmPasswordAuthentication(null, domain, userName, password))
SmbFile share = new SmbFile(url, context)
```

You can then copy the file that you want.

Comment: Thank you so much. Its a Windows Shared drive.  I'll try it and update you.